# Present view controller not working on real device

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that will direct user to another viewController once it is logged in.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let controller = HomeViewController()
                    controller.isLoggedIn = self.loggedIn
                    controller.userRole = self.userRole
                    controller.username = self.username

                    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

                    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                        navigationController.isModalInPresentation = true
                        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                    }
                    print("should present here")
                    self.present(navigationController, animated: true)

            }
```

Above is the "redirecting" part. This code works well in the simulator, but on the real device it does not work. Any idea how I can solve it? Thanks!

Comment: what is the iOS version of real device? Xcode version?

Comment: IOS 13.3. Does it affect the presenting? I remember it used to work :( @MohamedMostafa

Comment: Can you debug on device and check whether it reaches present( line. Also printing self.presentedViewController would help

Comment: @MohamedMostafa it does reaches the present() when i added the print("should present here \(self.present(navigationController, animated: true))") it return ()

Comment: Okay I found out my simulator is IOS 12.2 once I changed it to a 13.4 simulator. The present wont work anymore.

Comment: please check my added answer with a suggestion that should fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the response but I fixed it by

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                        self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
                    }
```

apparently it didnt work as there was a error saying there was another view controller being presented ( i missed this error previously )

Answer (score 1):

Try this also Set home screen identifier in storyboard "HomeViewController"

In code:

let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

Answer (score 0):

Using .fullScreen as modalPresentationStyle should fix your issue and gives the default style used on iOS 12 or lower.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
} else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use storyBoard reference for presenting a viewController. Which you can do by using example of the below attached code:-

```
let VC1 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MyViewController") as! ViewController

`let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)` // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.

self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```